# A polynomial function on $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose all level sets are mutually non isometric Riemannian manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, polynomials, differential-topology

Is there  a  polynomial function  $P: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ with the following property?:

> P does not have any critical value and for  all $c \neq c'$, $f^{-1}(c)$ and $f^{-1}(c')$ are  non isometric  Riemannian manifolds(with the metric they inherit from the  standard metric of  $\mathbb{R}^3$)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The polynomial $P(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+\frac{z^3}{3}+z$ has no critical values. Any level set $L_c := P^{-1}(c)$ is a surface of revolution around the $z$-axis. Here's an image of the $L_c$ for $c=-30,-15,0,15,30$ (drawn in SageMath):

[image: $L_c$ for $c=-30,-15,0,15,30$]

Actually, any level set $L_c$ has a unique Killing vector field $X_c$ which vanishes just at one point $O_c$. Let $K(c)$ (resp. $LK(c)$) be the Gauss curvature of $L_c$ at $O_c$ (resp. the value of the Laplace-Beltrami operator applied to the Gauss curvature of $L_c$ at $O_c$). If $L_c$ and $L_{c'}$ are isometric then $K(c)=K(c')$ and $LK(c)=LK(c')$. Using software I got that $K(c)=K(c')$ iff $c=-c'$. Again using the computer, I got $LK(c) \neq LK(-c)$ for all $c$. Here are the formulae, where $u=(\sqrt{9 c^2+4}+3 c)/2$: $$K(c) = \frac{4}{(u^{2/3}-1+u^{-2/3})^2},$$
$$LK(c)=\frac{128 \sqrt[3]{u} \left(-1-\sqrt[3]{u}+u^{2/3}\right) \left(2u+3 c+9c^2u\right)}{\sqrt{9 c^2+4} \left(1-u^{2/3}+u^{4/3}\right)^4}.$$

Comment: I added a picture; hope that's all right.

Comment: @j.c. : thank you for the picture and for improving the answer.

Comment: @Holonomia  Thank you very  much for  your  great and interesting idea. I  need  times to understand its details. But just  another question: On the opposite extreme :  is there a  polynomial  $P(x,y,z)$  without critical value such that all level sets  are isometric  Riemannian manifold  but $P$ is  not in the  form $z+Q(x,y)$, after  a possible  permutation in $x,y,z$ and  scalar  multiplication?

Comment: Moreover, is  there some thing as geometric version of  Morse theory?

Comment: @Ali Taghavi: I think you mean that $P$ is not of the form $c \cdot H \circ g$ where $g$ is an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^3$, $c$ a constant and $H$ of the form $z + Q(x,y)$. But anyway I do not know if this happen. No idea about geometric Morse theory.

Comment: Can I ask you  to expand your answer?In particular  how you find the unique Killing vector field?  Moreover  can the same argument as in your answer be  applied to the following question:

Comment: Are all (cylinder) level sets of $p(z,w)= z^2 + w^2$  mutually isometric? (We consider them as 2,dimensional submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^4 \simeq \mathbb{C}^2$ with the standard  metric  $dx^2+dŷ2+dz^2+dŵ2$.?

Comment: @Ali Taghavi: The existence of the Killing vector field $X_c$ is obvious being $L_c$ a surface of revolution. The uniqueness of such Killing vector field (up to a multiple, of course) is a consequence of the fact that the Gauss curvature of the level sets $L_c$ is not constant i.e. the existence of another Killing vector field independent of $X_c$ would imply that $L_c$ has constant Gauss curvature.  Finally, I do not understand you query about $p(z,w)=z^2 + w^2$. Are $z,w$ the complex coordinates of $\mathbb{C}$?  who are $x, \hat{y}, \hat{w}$ ?

Comment: @Holonomia  thank you for your comment.  Yes,  z and w are   complex numbers.  Th

Comment: x,y^,w^ they were typos. They are usual x,y,z,w. The metric of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is denoted by  $dx^2+dy ^2 +dz^2 + dw ^2$  where we identify  $(x,y,z,w)$ with  $(x+iy,  z+iw)$.

Comment: @Ali Taghavi: still do not understand. You wrote $z,w$ are complex numbers, but then you also wrote $z + i w$ which means that $z,w$ are reals.

Comment: @Holonomia  You  are write. The  correct  is  the  following $(z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^2$ correspond to  $(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^4$ where $z=x_1+iy_1,\; w=x_2+iy_2$. The metric  of  $\mathbb{R}^4$ is read as $dx_1^2+dy_1^2 +dx_2^2+dy_2^2$.

Comment: @Holonomia  Thanks again for your answer. I get the sketch of strategy of your answer but I confess thatI have to effort to understand its details. But this post is a motivation to consider a "Bundle" analogy of this question as follows:

Comment: Let we have a smooth ( vector or fiber) bundle. Can we equipe the total space to a Riemannian metric such that all fibers are isometric.(In the opposite direction we may require that all fibers all mutually non isometric). Existence of obstructions for such metric is an indication of high strongly non triviality of the bundle? What type of "characteristics" would appear in this way?